# Pound and Euro symbol not shown in windows form instead showing a J

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, currency, symbols

We wrote a program that behaves differently on two equal machines.
On one machine is shows the price with a pound symbol.  We set the symbol based upon a list e.g.
    { "£", "€", "€" };
Both machines are configured with the same language and keyboard settings.
We don't depend on currency settings, but even so the currency setting on both machines are the same.
But on one machine, the symbol is "translated" to the letter J.
We have this with a label on a windows form, using C# 2010 and wonder what could cause it?

update
I use the same font and same method to display it.
Both machines run Win7 sp1
And its not only with the pound symbol also the Euro symbol is shown as a J ???

Comment: Are you using the same font?

Comment: How are you writing the string? Did you set an Encoding parameter?

Comment: I use the same font, checked with notepad this font does contain the symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with something thanks to my awesome Google-fu, but I could only test it on my one mahcine, so I'm not sure if it'll do it for you, but give it a shot anyway.

```
var encoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(858); //also tried with 437
byte[] c = new byte[] { 156 };
Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(c));
```

This prints out "£" on my machine.

Taken from this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/dccd38e0-6f9e-4fb2-b114-bc44128ca634/

Comment: More info on the encoding values:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding.aspx

Comment: we write the euro and pound symbols directly in our code.
this works fine on the machines we develop on but we get this problem on the client pc for which we build the software

Comment: Yes, I understand. Instead of typing the pound symbol directly try using the code I put above. "c" is the pound symbol, so you could do like `Label1.Text += encoder.GetString(c)` to add the pound symbol at the end of the Label's text.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with websites (our own and one from other well established websites) where the pound (£) symbol showed as a letter J. We also noticed that at the same time the text was bold and oblique when it shouldn't have been.

After much investigation it turned out that much of the machines we came across had something wrong with the Helvetica font installed on the machines, and there are two possible solutions:

1. If you have control over the machines delete the "Helvetica Bold Oblique",  "Helvetica Bold" and "Helvetica Oblique" fonts ("Helvetica Regular" seems to work fine).
2. Use a different font in your applications/websites.